# Media Formats in Android?

Tags: android

What is the Difference between Encoder and Decoder in [Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) in android? What is the Need of it? Which is the recommended image Format by you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a decoder, you can playback (listen or view) the media type. If you have an encoder, you can create the media type (record, take pictures, film) on your Android device.

Recommended media type depends on what you want to use it for. What is your audience? What decoders do they have? What quality do you require?

Comment: if i use png for my app background its some what blurry. but not in jpg images. Why its happening?